# "Aw snap" error on opening the console window - chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome

Getting an "Aw snap" error on opening the console window - chrome on my local environment(IIS Server).I am using Angular 2 with http call to api.

without console window open its working but the response time is longer than usual.

Chrome Version: Latest (60).

Can someone please help.

Comment: we need more than that

Comment: i hope you have solved error.please update what was the cause of the error. i had same issue and it was resolved as i was calling wrong component in html. please double check while copy paste.